# Reverse array elements with specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
$array = array( [0] => 'red1', [1] => 'blue1', [2] => 'red2', [3] => 'red3', [4] => 'blue2' );
```

A want to reverse order of elements with red value only so it looks like this:

```
$array = array( [0] => 'red3', [1] => 'blue1', [2] => 'red2', [3] => 'red1', [4] => 'blue2' );
```

Comment: How to reverse only red elements without touching anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a possible solution might be to:

1. Get all the values from the `$array` that you are looking for and
   store them in an array `$found`
2. Reverse the values in `$found` keeping the keys
3. Replace the values in `$array` with the values from `$found` using
   the key

For example:

```
$array = array(0 => 'red1', 1 => 'blue1', 2 => 'red2', 3 => 'red3', 4 => 'blue2');

// First get all the values with 'red' and store them in an array
$found = preg_grep('/red\d+/', $array);

// Reverse the values, keeping the keys
$found = array_combine(
    array_keys($found),
    array_reverse(
        array_values($found)
    )
);

// Then replace the values of $array with values having the same keys in $found
$array = array_replace($array, $found);

var_dump($array);
```

Will result in:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "red3"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "blue1"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "red2"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "red1"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "blue2"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch red's quote to a new array and sort them.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
     'red1', 
     'blue1', 
     'red2', 
     'red3', 
     'blue2'
);

$sortArr = array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) { 
    if(strstr($arr[$i], "red")){
        $sortArr[] = &$arr[$i];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do using searching specific words by `strpos` and sorting array by `ksort` (sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {        
if(strpos($value,"red") !== false){
    ($key === 0) ? $index = 3 : (($key === 3) ? $index = 0 : $index = 2);
    $temp[$index] = $value;
}
else {
    $temp[$key] = $value;
}   
}
ksort($temp);
var_dump($temp);
```

[But It will not work in larger array than this]